# How to read txt files into an array that are stored into class variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, database, class, fstream

```
       #include <iostream>
       #include <fstream>
       #include <string> 
       #include <vector>

       using namespace std;

       class BasketballPlayer
       {
       public:
           void printBasketballPlayer() const;

           BasketballPlayer(); //Constructor with Parameters
       
       
          
       private:
           string name;
           float MinutesPlayed;
           float PlayerScoreEffRating;
           float Steals;
           float AST;
           float PointPerGame;
           float Rebounds;
           float FieldGoal;
           float FreeThrow;
           float ThreePointers;
           float BLK;
           float TurnOver;
   
  
       };
       class BasketballTeam
       {
       public:
           string name;
           void printBasketballTeam() const;
           bool findPlayer(string &);
           void editPlayer(bool&);
           BasketballTeam(); //Default Constructor
           void getName()
           {
               getline(cin, name);
           }


       private:
           //void BasketballPlayer();
           string name;
           float MinutesPlayed;
           float PlayerScoreEffRating;
           float Steals;
           float AST;
           float PointPerGame;
           float Rebounds;
           float FieldGoal;
           float FreeThrow;
           float ThreePointers;
           float BLK;
           float TurnOver;
           string myArray[16][11];
           string PlayerName[15];
           float myArray[15][11];
           void Team() 
           {
               ifstream file("TextFileTeam.txt");
               if (file.is_open())
               {
                   string myArray[16];

                   for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
                   {
                       file >> myArray[i];
             
                   }
               }
           }
       };



       int main()
       {
           BasketballPlayer Play;
           string Search;
           bool isPlayerThere;
           char Change;
           BasketballTeam Team;

           cout << " Welcome to the Brooklyn Net's Stats and DataBase " << endl;
           cout << " These are the stats of our new SuperStar " << endl;
   
              Play.printBasketballPlayer();

              cout << " < Would you Like to Update stats of the roster > --> Y or --> N " << endl;
              cin >> Change;
              cout << endl;

              if (Change == 'Y' || 'y')
              {
                  Team.findPlayer(Search);

                  Team.editPlayer(isPlayerThere);

              }
              else
              {
                  Team.printBasketballTeam();
              }
  

              Team.printBasketballTeam();

  
              return 0;
          }//end main

          void BasketballPlayer::printBasketballPlayer() const
          {
   
              cout << "|| The players name || " << this->name;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Minutes Per Game || " << this->MinutesPlayed;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Turnovers Per Game || " << this->TurnOver;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Points Per Game || " << this->PointPerGame;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Rebounds Per Game || " << this->Rebounds;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Asists Per Game || " << this->AST;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Blocks Per Game || " << this->BLK;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| 3 Point % || " << this->ThreePointers;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Free-Throw % || " << this->FreeThrow;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Field Goal %|| " << this->FieldGoal;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Steals % || " <<  this->Steals;
              cout << endl;

              cout << "|| Player Scoreing Effiencey Rating || " << this->PlayerScoreEffRating;
              cout << endl;
   
          }
        

          BasketballPlayer::BasketballPlayer() //Constructor with Parameters
          {
              name = "James Harden";
              MinutesPlayed = 40.2f;
              TurnOver = 4.2f;
              PointPerGame = 24.1f;
              Rebounds = 8.1f;
              AST = 12.0f;
              BLK = 0.6f;
              ThreePointers = 37.9f;
              FreeThrow = 89.2f;
              FieldGoal = 48.2f;
              Steals = 1.1f;
              PlayerScoreEffRating = 1.561f;

          }

          void BasketballTeam::printBasketballTeam() const
          {
              ifstream file("TextFileTeam.txt");
              if (file.is_open())
              {
                  string myArray[16];

                  for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
                  {
                      file >> myArray[i];
                      cout << myArray[i];
                      cout << endl;
                  }
              }
          }
          bool BasketballTeam::findPlayer(string&)
          {
              bool Finder = false;
              const char *name;

              switch (*name)
              {
              case  1:
                  if(name == "Kevin_Durant")
                  Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  2:
                  if (name == "Kyrie_Irving")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  3:
                  if (name == "James_Harden")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  4:
                  if (name == "Joe_Harris")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  5:
                  if (name == "Jarrett_Allen")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  6:
                  if (name == "Jeff_Green")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  7:
                  if (name == "Taurean_Prince")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  8:
                  if (name == "Timothe_Luwawu - Cabarrot")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  9:
                  if (name == "Spencer_Dinwiddie")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  10:
                  if (name == "DeAndre_Jordan")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  11:
                  if (name == "Bruce_Brown_Jr.")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  12:
                  if (name == "Landry_Shamet")
                      Finder = true;
                  break;
              case  13:
                   if (name == "Chris_Chiozza")
                       Finder = true;
                   break;
              case  14:
                   if (name == "Reggie_Perry")
                        Finder = true;
                    break;
              case  15:
                   if (name == "Tyler_Johnson")
                       Finder = true;
                    break;
              default:
                  cout << " Player not in Roster " << endl;
                  break;
              }


              return Finder;
          }
          void BasketballTeam::editPlayer(bool &)
          {
              int editValue;   
              BasketballTeam Team;
              bool isThere;
   
              ifstream file("JustData.txt");
              if (file.is_open())
              {
                  string myArray[15];

                  for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
                  {
          
                      file >> myArray[i];
           
                  }
              }


                       if (isThere == true)
                      {
       
                  cout << " What would you like to edit? " << endl;
                  cout << "[1] Mintues, [2] Turnover, [3] Points Per Game, [4] Rebounds Per Game, [5]                                                                        
                  Steals Per                   
                  Game, [6] Free Throw %, [7] Assits Per Game, [8] Filed Goal %" << endl;
                  cout << "[7] Assits Per Game, [8] Filed Goal %[9] 3P%, [10] Player Scoring Eff, [11]           
                  Blocks Per Game ---> ";
                  cin >> editValue;

                  switch (editValue)
               {
               case 1:
                   MinutesPlayed = editValue;
                    break;
               case 2:
                   PlayerScoreEffRating = editValue;
                   break;
               case 3:
                   PointPerGame = editValue;
                   break;
               case 4:
                   Rebounds = editValue;
                   break;
               case 5:
                   Steals = editValue;
                   break;
               case 6:
                   FreeThrow = editValue;
                   break;
               case 7:
                   AST = editValue;
                   break;
               case 8:
                   FieldGoal = editValue;
                   break;
               case 9:
                   ThreePointers = editValue;
                   break;
               case 10:
                   PlayerScoreEffRating = editValue;
                   break;
               case 11:
                   BLK = editValue;
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
               }
           }
           
       }

       BasketballTeam::BasketballTeam() //Default Constructor
       {
           int j;
           int row;
           int col;
           j = 0;
           ifstream file("JustData.txt");
           if (file.is_open())
           {
               float PlayerArray[15][11];


               for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
               {
                   for (int col = 0; col < 11; col++)
                   {

                       file >> PlayerArray[row][col];
                       MinutesPlayed = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       TurnOver = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       Rebounds = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       PointPerGame = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       AST = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       BLK = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       ThreePointers = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       FreeThrow = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       FieldGoal = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       Steals = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       PlayerScoreEffRating = PlayerArray[j][col];
                       j++;
           }
               }
       
           }
           ifstream file2("JustNames.txt");
           if (file2.is_open())
           {
    
               string PlayerName[15];

               for (int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
               {
                   file >> PlayerName[row];
                   name = PlayerName[row];
               }
           }
       };
```

JustData.txt
36.9,3.5,7.5,5.2,0.8,1.4,30.8,53.3,45.2,87.8,1.575
35.8,2.3,4.8,5.7,1,0.8,28.3,53.5,44.7,94.8,1.403
40.3,4.2,8.1,12,1.1,0.6,24.1,48.2,37.9,89.2,1.561
31.7,0.9,3.7,2.1,0.6,0.3,14.9,51.2,48.7,61.5,1.361
26.6,1.8,10.4,1.7,0.6,1.6,11.2,67.7,0,75.4,2.062
25.7,1,3.8,1.4,0.7,0.2,8.9,54.1,44.7,83.3,1.519
18.1,0.9,2.8,0.6,0.7,0.7,8.1,40.5,35.1,88.9,1.311
19,0.6,2.2,1.3,0.6,0.2,7.3,38.3,36.3,72.2,1.091
21.4,1.7,4.3,3,0.7,0.3,6.7,37.5,28.6,100,1.25
20.3,1.6,6.9,1.7,0.3,1.4,6.6,81.3,0,48.4,1.813
17.6,0.9,4.2,0.9,0.5,0.4,5.9,58.8,17.6,71.4,1.329
17.2,0.8,1.4,1.1,0.6,0.2,5.6,34.4,29.6,84,1.14
11.2,0.8,1,2.5,0.5,0.4,4,28.2,29.4,71.4,0.821
10.5,0.8,3.6,0.9,0.1,0.4,3.6,41.2,16.7,66.7,0.98
6.2,0.3,0.7,1.1,0.4,0,1.3,30,42.9,0,0.9

JustNames.txt
Kevin_Durant
Kyrie_Irving
James_Harden
Joe_Harris
Jarrett_Allen
Jeff_Green
Taurean_Prince
Timothe_Luwawu-Cabarrot
Spencer_Dinwiddie
DeAndre_Jordan
Bruce_Brown_Jr.
Landry_Shamet
Chris_Chiozza
Reggie_Perry
Tyler_Johnson

TeamNoTitle.txt
Kevin_Durant,36.9,3.5,7.5,5.2,0.8,1.4,30.8,53.3,45.2,87.8,1.575
Kyrie_Irving,35.8,2.3,4.8,5.7,1,0.8,28.3,53.5,44.7,94.8,1.403
James_Harden,40.3,4.2,8.1,12,1.1,0.6,24.1,48.2,37.9,89.2,1.561
Joe_Harris,31.7,0.9,3.7,2.1,0.6,0.3,14.9,51.2,48.7,61.5,1.361
Jarrett_Allen,26.6,1.8,10.4,1.7,0.6,1.6,11.2,67.7,0,75.4,2.062
Jeff_Green,25.7,1,3.8,1.4,0.7,0.2,8.9,54.1,44.7,83.3,1.519
Taurean_Prince,18.1,0.9,2.8,0.6,0.7,0.7,8.1,40.5,35.1,88.9,1.311
Timothe_Luwawu-Cabarrot,19,0.6,2.2,1.3,0.6,0.2,7.3,38.3,36.3,72.2,1.091
Spencer_Dinwiddie,21.4,1.7,4.3,3,0.7,0.3,6.7,37.5,28.6,100,1.25
DeAndre_Jordan,20.3,1.6,6.9,1.7,0.3,1.4,6.6,81.3,0,48.4,1.813
Bruce_Brown_Jr.,17.6,0.9,4.2,0.9,0.5,0.4,5.9,58.8,17.6,71.4,1.329
Landry_Shamet,17.2,0.8,1.4,1.1,0.6,0.2,5.6,34.4,29.6,84,1.14
Chris_Chiozza,11.2,0.8,1,2.5,0.5,0.4,4,28.2,29.4,71.4,0.821
Reggie_Perry,10.5,0.8,3.6,0.9,0.1,0.4,3.6,41.2,16.7,66.7,0.98
Tyler_Johnson,6.2,0.3,0.7,1.1,0.4,0,1.3,30,42.9,0,0.9

TeamFileNets.txt
Player,MPG,TOV,RPG,APG,SPG,BPG,PPG,FG%,3P%,FT%,SC-EFF
Kevin_Durant,36.9,3.5,7.5,5.2,0.8,1.4,30.8,53.3,45.2,87.8,1.575
Kyrie_Irving,35.8,2.3,4.8,5.7,1,0.8,28.3,53.5,44.7,94.8,1.403
James_Harden,40.3,4.2,8.1,12,1.1,0.6,24.1,48.2,37.9,89.2,1.561
Joe_Harris,31.7,0.9,3.7,2.1,0.6,0.3,14.9,51.2,48.7,61.5,1.361
Jarrett_Allen,26.6,1.8,10.4,1.7,0.6,1.6,11.2,67.7,0,75.4,2.062
Jeff_Green,25.7,1,3.8,1.4,0.7,0.2,8.9,54.1,44.7,83.3,1.519
Taurean_Prince,18.1,0.9,2.8,0.6,0.7,0.7,8.1,40.5,35.1,88.9,1.311
Timothe_Luwawu-Cabarrot,19,0.6,2.2,1.3,0.6,0.2,7.3,38.3,36.3,72.2,1.091
Spencer_Dinwiddie,21.4,1.7,4.3,3,0.7,0.3,6.7,37.5,28.6,100,1.25
DeAndre_Jordan,20.3,1.6,6.9,1.7,0.3,1.4,6.6,81.3,0,48.4,1.813
"Bruce_Brown_Jr.",17.6,0.9,4.2,0.9,0.5,0.4,5.9,58.8,17.6,71.4,1.329
Landry_Shamet,17.2,0.8,1.4,1.1,0.6,0.2,5.6,34.4,29.6,84,1.14
Chris_Chiozza,11.2,0.8,1,2.5,0.5,0.4,4,28.2,29.4,71.4,0.821
Reggie_Perry,10.5,0.8,3.6,0.9,0.1,0.4,3.6,41.2,16.7,66.7,0.98
Tyler_Johnson,6.2,0.3,0.7,1.1,0.4,0,1.3,30,42.9,0,0.9

I'm sure that I'm not understanding Classes. Trying to use fstream to hold data of players so that my classes and driver code can change those files then display data from stored data in classes. I have no syntax errors but code not running. Most likey because of me reading file into array wrong to get data into my classes from file and improper calling of classes in main function.

Comment: Unfortunaltely I can only post 5 duplicate links. There are probably many more duplicates and related questions to be found at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding  the class variables, remember that these have a `private` access scope. So you'll need to provide either appropriate getter and setter functions, or the parsing using `std::istream` as a class member function (e.g. `std::istream& parseFromStream(std::istream& is);`).

Comment: Can u give me a example having trouble understanding how to access of class scopes and declaring Classes with name to hold my data.

Comment: _"... having trouble understanding how to access of class scopes and declaring Classes with name to hold my data"_ That doesn't have to do anything with the question you asked here. To learn about such basic things like organizing variables in `class`es and `struct's, I'd recommend you first study some [beginner level book or tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before starting to code more complex things. You can't expecrt to be tutored at Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: Looking for a fresh pair of eyes because yes I'm learning classes. Looking for someone to see my code and point me in the right direction. Example that I can see and build off with context to what I have on my screen. Since you have looked at my code any duplicate links you can share? I haven't been having much luck.